# Dynamic measure to display results for current year and previous 2 years

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax

I have a measure which works fine but I want it to display the results dynamically for the current year and last 2 years instead of me manually selecting the years.

Is this possible?

Here are my current measures:

```
DistinctAccount = DISTINCTCOUNT('AccountTable'[AccountId])
```

and

```
AccountMembers =
CALCULATE (
    [DistinctAccount],
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
        ( 'Calendar'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) )
    ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( Identifier[Termination Year] ),
        ( Identifier[Termination Year] > SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Year] ) )
    )
)
```

Comment: Definitely possible. Can you provide some sample data and desired output?